# iptables : did I understand these commands correctly?

Tags: firewall

Take a look at this set of commands :

```
iptables -F

iptables -P OUTPUT DR0P
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -d 195.83.164.0/23 -p udp --dport 53 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 195.83.164.0/23 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j REJECT
```

Tell me if the following points are correct :

1. The line N°1 flushes all the chains (FORWARD, INPUT, OUTPUT...) of all the tables (MANGLE, NAT, FILTER, ...)
2. The lines N°2, N°3, N°4 sets the default table's (FILTER) OUTPUT/INPUT/FORWARD chains' default action to DROP
3. First of all, any packet is analyzed by MANGLE's PREROUTING chain : nothing is indicated, so we suppose that the default action is ACCEPT
4. Then it will be analyzed by NAT's PREROUTING chain : same
5. Then, the destination address of the packet is read........ :
6. IF THE PACKET IS NOT DESTINATED TO THE ROUTER ("NDTR"), THEN... :
7. The NDTR packet is analysed by MANGLE's FORWARD chain : nothing is indicated, so we suppose that the default action is ACCEPT
8. Then, the NDTR packet is analyzed by FILTER's FORWARD chain : the lines N°5, N°6, N°7, N°8 and N°4 tell that the NDTR packet will be ACCEPTED only if [ its destination is 195.83.164.0/23 AND destination port is 53 AND destination interface is eth0 ] OR if [ its source is 195.83.164.0/23 AND destination port is 53 ] OR if [ its an SSH packet ] ELSE, it will be DROPPED.
9. If the NDTR packet is DROPPED, then... well... it's DROPPED, and it's the end of this "algorithm". Otherwise, if it's ACCEPTED, it will be analyzed by the MANGLE's POSTROUTING chain : nothing is indicated, we suppose the default action is ACCEPT : then, it will be analyzed by NAT's POSTROUTING chain : nothing is indicated, ACCEPT by default again. Then, the packet has reached its destination.
10. OTHERWISE, IF THE PACKET IS ACTUALLY DESTINATED TO THIS ROUTER ("DR") ..... :
11. The DR packet will be analyzed by MANGLE's INPUT chain : nothing is indicated, we assume ACCEPT
12. Then, the DR packet will be analyzed by the FILTER's INPUT chain : it will be REJECTED if its destination interface is eth0, or DROPPED if not.
13. In both case, it's the end.
14. Just for information : the packet would be analyzed then by MANGLE's OUTPUT chain then by NAT's OUTPUT chain then by FILTER's OUTPUT chain then by MANGLE's POSTROUTING chain then by NAT's POSTROUTING chain, then it will be returned to the host that sent it.

Well, did I correctly understand Netfilter/iptables ?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting things mostly right, A couple of minor points.

1. The NAT engine is connection-based. Only the first packet of a connection goes through the NAT chains. For later packets in the connection translations are performed based on the mappings created by the first packet. I'm not sure exactly where in the process the translations for existing packets are applied.
2. Your description seems to have missed the MASQUERADE rule in the nat table POSTROUTING chain.

Comment: Correct ! My point N°9 should be edited. Indeed, the source of any packet leaving the interface ppp0 and coming from 192.168.1.0/24 is replaced by the router's IP server associated to its interface ppp0.